# Calculate current quarter Fiscal_start date based off 13 week (91 day) rolling quarters

Tags: sql, date, oracle-sqldeveloper, calculation

I am looking for a SQL solution to work in Oracle Developer SQL that will calculate the current quarters start and end date based off of sysdate and that the Fiscal calendar starts on Feb 1, 2020. Each quarter is a Fixed 13 weeks (91 days) -- NOT 3 months, therefore each year has a slightly different fiscal calendar.
Code will be uploaded to automated reporting and do not want to adjust it each year.
Current year fiscal calendar attached as sample explanation. 
[Current Fiscal Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFD2A.png)

I started to head down this road but got lost when i realized the start date wasnt able to be correct in this format.

End solution would be used for a where clause to determine reporting date range such as
( Where Report_Date between Modified_Quarter_Start and sysdate )

```
select trunc(add_months(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'Y') -1 ,
to_number(to_char(sysdate,'Q')) * 3),-1),'MM') 
start_date,trunc(add_months(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'Y') -1 ,
to_number(to_char(sysdate,'Q')) * 3),+2),'MM')-1 Endd_date,
add_months(trunc(sysdate,'Y') -1 ,to_number(to_char(sysdate,'Q')) * 3) end_date ,
to_char(sysdate,'YYYY - q') qtr from dual
```

Greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: So your quarter always starts on a sunday and every year 1 or 2 days earlier? This should return the 1st day of the quarter: `date '2020-02-01' + (trunc((current_date - date '2020-02-01') / 91) * 91)`, add 90 days to get the last_day

Comment: Please provide more sample data.  For instance, what is the fiscal date of 2021-01-31?  Of 2022-01-31?  Of 2030-01-31?

Comment: appears i was typing as you were, please see below.  for  2021-01-31 fiscal date would be Q1 of FY22.  it is a very strange way of fiscal calendars for a company that large.

Comment: Quarter would actually always start on a Saturday

Answer (score 0):

Posting incase someone else runs into the same predicement in the future. 
After reading a mention of a case statement for fixed days in another thread, i thought of this solution.

```
Select Trunc(sysdate - to_date('02-Feb-2019')), 
Case When Trunc(sysdate - to_date('02-Feb-2019')) > 91 Then to_date('02-Feb-2019') + 
Round( to_number(Trunc(sysdate - to_date('02-Feb-2019'))/91),0) * 91 
Else null End Current_Quarter_Start, 
Case When Trunc(sysdate - to_date('02-Feb-2019')) > 91 Then to_date('02-Feb-2019') + 
( (Round( to_number(Trunc(sysdate - to_date('02-Feb-2019'))/91),0) +1 )* 91)-1 Else null End Current_Quarter_End From Dual
```

Comment: Did you try my calculation?

Comment: yes, to get current quarter that works fine, but not for future quarters. the solution i posted above accounts for future quarters.

Comment: Of course it's working for future quarters, too. Simply use any date instead of sysdate/current_date. Try it against your calendar table (assuming you already got one)